# I'm trying to update and delete a user and i get this error " 'user' object is not iterable"

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to update and delete a user, but while I am iterating threw users in view.py I get 'User' object is not iterable

in index.html

```html
{% block body %}
       <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        {% for user23 in context %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{{user23.id}}">delete</a></td>
                <td>{{ user23.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ user23.name}}</td>
                <td>{{ user23.age}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{%endblock%}
```

in forms.py

```
class userform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'age']
        model = user
```

in urls.py

```
  urlpatterns = [
    #/library/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^createprofile/$', views.createpro, name='createprofile'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.updateuser, name='updateuser'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', views.deleteuser, name='deleteuser'),
  ]
```

in views.py

```
def index(request):
    context = user.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'context': context})

def createpro(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = userform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')#render(request, 'createprofile.html', 
    {'form': form})
    else:
        form = userform()
    return render(request, 'createprofile.html', {'form': form})

def updateuser(request, id):
    context = user.objects.get(pk=id)
    form = userform(request.POST or None, instance=context)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'context': context, 'form':form})

def deleteuser(request, id):
    context = user.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context.delete()
        return redirect('index')

    return render(request, 'deleteuser.html', {'context':context})
```

in model.py

```
class user(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

please help me where the error is?

please ignore this block of text
**********I have 3 models: User, Choice, Card. Each user will look at the same set of 10 cards and decides each one is important or not.Here are how I define the classes and their relationship

In models.py:

thanks! ☺☺☺

Comment: add your traceback in question

Comment: post your error!